# Updating the pom.xml with Eclipse

Tags: java, m2eclipse

Using Eclipse with the m2eclipse plug-in, how do I update the pom.xml, so the “Maven->Update Project” won’t reset the project configuration back to Java 1.5?
I am using Eclipse Kepler 4.3, Java 7, and the m2eclipse plug-in.
I create a new Maven project with “Create a simple project (skip archetype selection)” checked and the artifactId “test”. I get the following warning.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.   test        Build path  JRE System Library Problem

I use the following steps the change the compiler from 1.5 to 1.7.
1.  On the project, do right-click “Properties” and select the “Java build path”.
2.  Go to the “Libraries” tab.
3.  Remove the old JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.5].
4.  Click “Add Library…”, select “JRE System Library”, and click “Next>”.
5.  Check “Execution environment” radio button and select “JavaSE 1.7 …” from the adjoining menu.
6.  Click “Finish”
7.  Click “OK”.

The warning disappears.

I right-click the project and select “Maven->Update Project”. I click “OK”.

The warning message returns.

My understanding is the plugin uses the pom.xml to update Eclipse’s current settings. How do I update the pom.xml, so the “Maven->Update Project” won’t reset the project configuration back to Java 1.5?

I looked at these pages, but I think the answers are obsolete.
[Warning - Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/java-warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4)
[What causes a new Maven project in Eclipse to use Java 1.5 instead of Java 1.6 by default and how can I ensure it doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539139/what-causes-a-new-maven-project-in-eclipse-to-use-java-1-5-instead-of-java-1-6-b)
[maven does not compile in java 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808529/maven-does-not-compile-in-java-1-6)

For example, adding …

`<configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>`

… after the version section in the POM doesn’t fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the maven compiler plugin.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Tell maven to compile using Java 1.7 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I updated pom.xml to look like this.`<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aglx</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</project>`This did NOTsolve the problem.

Comment: 1. You're missing the build tag around your plugins.
2. Comments are a terrible place to put code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the Maven Compiler Plugin to use a specific version

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```